# Warning C6387 Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, warnings

What is `Visual Studio` trying to tell me with this warning?

[image: Warning]

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6387?view=msvc-160), this warning is when you're passing a potentially null value to a parameter.

But I'm checking for null with `if (hwnd)` before calling these functions.

```cpp
if (hwnd) {
    GetClientRect(hwnd, (LPRECT)&rMyRect);
    ClientToScreen(hwnd, (LPPOINT)&rMyRect.left);
    ClientToScreen(hwnd, (LPPOINT)&rMyRect.right);
}
```

Comment: It's trying to tell you it's too clever for its own good.

Comment: Try closing the *.cpp file and opening it again. Maybe it will make it shut up.

Comment: If you can construct a [mcve], you should [file a defect](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/), and let people here know so that it gets upvoted. When reporting bugs in the native developer tools, Microsoft generally doesn't care, unless there's a high vote count. Apparently, Nadella doesn't understand that there's real code required to power his *"Intelligent Edge"*.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you test for it is not relevant, the compiler isn't detecting that test.
You can, however, use:

```
#pragma warning(suppress : 6387)
```

on the prior line and that will prevent the message (or use __Pragma(warning(suppress : 6387)) but I prefer the #pragma form.

Comment: That would stop the warning being generated at compile time but I don't think it'll stop the "intellisense" warning.

Comment: Would it be better to do a pragma push before the suppress, and a pragma pop after the calls to `ClientToScreen`?

Comment: #pragma warning(push)/#pragma warning(pop) only make sense when paired with #pragma warning(disable :), not #pragma warning(suppress : ), suppress is a one-time command, it only applies to the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Being the IntelliSense undeline what you are trying to get rid of (not the compile-time warning), it looks like there is no specific option to force IntelliSense to ignore that warning. You could disable it as a whole from the Visual Studio window, under *Tools*->*Options*->*Text Editor*->*C/C++*->*Advanced*, Look at the right for the section "Code Analysis"; under this section, set "*Disable C++ Code Analysis Experience*" to **True.**

[Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->*Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbXWm.png)

Comment: But I don't want to disable all warnings, only this one!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I disable warning 6387 for just the block of affected code;

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 6387)
    GetClientRect(hwnd, (LPRECT)&rMyRect);
    ClientToScreen(hwnd, (LPPOINT)&rMyRect.left);
    ClientToScreen(hwnd, (LPPOINT)&rMyRect.right);
#pragma warning( pop )
```

And thanks to ScienceDiscoverer for pointing out my mistake and that NULL is in fact defined as 0.

Comment: No, `NULL` is define din Windows API as 0. `nullptr` is a different beast, yes.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you can use the 'Source-code Annotation Language' (SAL) to tell IntelliSense about your check for `NULL` by adding

```
_Analysis_assume_(hwnd != NULL);
```

between the opening brace and the call to GetClientRect().