# C external errors and 1 warning

Tags: c, warnings, symbols

I am getting these errors when trying to compile, and the only thing underlined is strcpy_s(name, strlen(input)+1, input); Which is the warning. This is part of an assignment and part of the instructions was to make both a Topic.c (the code below) and a Topic.h but no instructions on what to put in the .h file. I have never seen these errors before and have researched them but I cannot find references relevant to this issue. This is not a fix code assignment this should be ready to run I am only supposed to understand the concepts. Not sure what question to ask. I have checked several times to ensure the code was typed in correctly.

> LNK2019    unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

and

> LNK1120    1 unresolved externals

and 1 warning

> C6387  'name' could be '0':  this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'strcpy_s'.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>

   /*
   * Swap 1 method with scalars: why does this not work?
   */
   void swap1(int x, int y)
   {
       int temp = x;
       x = y;
       y = temp;
   }

   /*
   * swap 2 method with pointers: why does this work?
   */
   void swap2(int* x, int* y)
   {
       int temp = *x;
       *x = *y;
       *y = temp;
   }

   /*
   * Play Pointer method: Don't forget to clean up your malloc!
   */
   char* playPointer(char* input)
   {
       // Allocate memory to hold a copy of the input array, copy input to it, and 
          return a pointer to a new array
       // What is the advantage of assigning address of a variable to a pointer 
          variable?
       // Why does swap1() not work, and why does swap2() work?
       // How does strpy_s() make code more secure?
       // How does strpy_s() demonstrate defensive coding?
       // Look up strncpy() and compare it to strpy_s() How are they similar?

       char* name = malloc(strlen(input)+1);
       strcpy_s(name, strlen(input)+1, input);
       return name;
   }
```

Comment: You're missing the `main()` function. If this is not the main program, use the `-c` option when compiling to just create a `.o` file, not try to link it.

Comment: The warning is because you didn't check whether `malloc()` succeeded.

Comment: Why do you have `'''` before and after the code? If you're trying to mark a code block, it should be 3 backticks, not quotes, and they should be on the line BEFORE the code. But since you've indented the code, you don't need that marker.

Comment: Not sure how to check if malloc succeeded. Tried adding the main do I need int main()? Thanks for the tip on submitting code

Comment: `if (name != NULL)`

Comment: I still get the same errors and also tried if (name != notNULL) just in case

Answer (score 0):

There is no `main` function in your code.

The `main` function in the `C` language is the program **entry point** and it has to be present to run the compiled program.

In your case the linker cant find it and reports the error.

Comment: I tried adding int main(void) outside of {} over the whole code but still get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

If this is supposed to be a standalone program, rather than something linked into other programs, it needs a `main()` function.

To suppress the warning about `name`, wrap the code that calls `strcpy_s()` in an `if` statement that checks that `malloc()` succeeded.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Swap 1 method with scalars: why does this not work?
 */
void swap1(int x, int y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

/*
 * swap 2 method with pointers: why does this work?
 */
void swap2(int* x, int* y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

/*
 * Play Pointer method: Don't forget to clean up your malloc!
 */
char* playPointer(char* input)
{
    // Allocate memory to hold a copy of the input array, copy input to it, and return a pointer to a new array
    // What is the advantage of assigning address of a variable to a pointer variable?
    // Why does swap1() not work, and why does swap2() work?
    // How does strpy_s() make code more secure?
    // How does strpy_s() demonstrate defensive coding?
    // Look up strncpy() and compare it to strpy_s() How are they similar?

    char* name = malloc(strlen(input)+1);
    if (name != NULL) {
        strcpy_s(name, strlen(input)+1, input);
    }
    return name;
}

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ill try that thanks

Comment: This it generated an output with nothing but code 0 but the warning remains about name could be 0. C6387 'name' could be '0': this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'strcpy_s'. Should I add delete name;   ? I read that somewhere, if so how do I define delete?

Comment: What output are you expected? The program doesn't do anything.

Comment: lol code 0 should be good enough just was worried that the name warning is still there Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69146879/warning-c6387-visual-studio The compiler isn't smart enough to detect that the check prevents that problem.

Comment: But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66821678/c6387-for-memcpy-strcpy-and-strcpy-s says that adding the null check should work. Maybe it depends on the version of MSVC.

Comment: Thanks again and I will check that link